# Codeigniter - If I have fetch row from 3 query, How to send from model to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3  and I have multiple queries look like below

```
<?php
class Address_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function fetchAddress()
    {


            $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
            $query = $this->db->get('member');
            $row = $query->row();

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM member_shipping_info WHERE member_id = ?";
            $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2, $row->member_id);
            $row2 = $query2->row();

                    $data['get_firstname'] = $row2->firstname;
                    $data['get_lastname'] = $row2->lastname;
                    $data['get_gender'] = $row2->gender;
                    $data['get_address'] = $row2->address;
                    $data['get_district'] = $row2->district;
                    $data['get_amphur'] = $row2->amphur;
                    $data['get_province'] = $row2->province;
                    $data['get_zipcode'] = $row2->zipcode;
                    $data['get_email'] = $row->email;
                    $data['get_phone'] = $row2->phone;


            $this->load->view('shopping/billing_view', $data);
```

The problem is it `$row->email`  it come from `$query1`  not 2  how should I send from model to controller and from controller to view? I put in model because I have to use these queries many times in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor your code. First, your `insertAddress` method name is misleading because it does not insert any address to database. Second, your code is doing too much things in one method. Third, setting view inside model is not very good MVC practice.

```
<?php
class Member_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getMemberData($username) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get('member');
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function getShippingInfo($member_id)
    {
         $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM member_shipping_info WHERE member_id = ?";
         $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2, $member_id);
         return $query2->row();
    }
}
```

Then inside your controller:

```
<?php
    ...
     $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
     $memberData = $memberModel->getMemberData($username);
     $shippingInfo = $memberModel->getShippingInfo($memberData->member_id);

     $data['get_firstname'] = $shippingInfo->firstname;
     $data['get_lastname'] = $shippingInfo->lastname;
     ...
     $data['get_email'] = $memberData->email;
     $data['get_phone'] = $shippingInfo->phone;

     $this->load->view('shopping/billing_view', $data);
```

Other alternative is to use SQL join to combine both queries in model into one query.

```
<?php
class Member_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getMemberShippingInfo($username)
    {
         $sql2 = "SELECT member.*, ".
                 "member_shipping_info.* ".
                 "FROM member ".
                 "INNER JOIN member_shipping_info ".
                 "ON member.member_id = member_shipping_info.member_id ".
                 "WHERE member.username = ?";

         $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2, $username);
         return $query2->row();
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
<?php
    ...
     $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
     $memberData = $memberModel->getMemberShippingInfo($username);

     $data['get_firstname'] = $memberData->firstname;
     $data['get_lastname'] = $memberData->lastname;
     ... 
     $data['get_email'] = $memberData->email;
     $data['get_phone'] = $memberData->phone;
```

Comment: "Third, setting view inside model is not very good MVC practice."  I put in model because I use these queries many times.   but if not good how should I do? if I want to use these queries many time

Comment: Model is supposed to be responsible for manipulating data not presentation. Presentation is responsibility of View.